# EF 6 - .NET6.0 - ASP.NET Code generator never works

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, blazor, .net-6.0

I'm wondering if anyone has a working solution to the code generator in ASP.NET .NET6.0 - EF 6

When working with Models and DBContext in different projects than the one where you're trying to add e.g. a Razor Page with EntityFramework CRUD:

[image]

The system generates errors. This is completely because of the models and DBContext being in different projects. But why have them in the same project? Why is this bug even a thing.
Solution: Put Models and DBContext in same project where you're trying to generate the page.
However, this is not solving it for me. And doing this means changing all the namespaces etc.

Using cmd line and aspnet-codegenerator like so:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Model -dc Context -udl -outDir Pages\GeneratedPage --referenceScriptLibraries
```

Does not work either. I'm using the aspnet-codegenerator 6.0.10.
Error:
[image]

I have tried tons of other suggestions and ran into other issues:

https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1412

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307012/attempting-to-compile-the-application-in-memory-wi.html

https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1702

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7291

I'm new to .Net, ASP.NET and Blazor. But I thought this code generation is supposed to make it easier for us devs? Isn't this just a template that gets filled based on the Entity you provide? Why not let us fix the compile errors instead of not generating anything? And what's with all the issues between the different .Net versions. Why make it so damn difficult, or am I?

Anyone have the template for a Razor Page based on entity with CRUD functions? I can just change the model and go further with this. This would be an answer to my issue. I have spent way too much time trying to fix this code generator.

If you know what i'm doing wrong here that would be great, but after all the posts and solutions i've been through I don't have any hope.

Comment: Why are you trying to generate Razor Pages in a Blazor application?

Comment: @MikeBrind What do you even mean by that, elaborate man. When I add components or pages through UI it says 'Razor page or Razor component'. That's what they are called. The reason why is stated in the question, CRUD functions on a page for an entity. So your comment is not helpful at all. Where are Blazor pages? What should I generate according to you in Blazor for CRUD functions on an entity in a page?

Comment: @MikeBrind This is where I first learned about Blazor:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/getting-started-blazor

All my Blazor components have a class with the code and a component called: ComponentName.Razor.

What is wrong here according to you?

All I want is a template for CRUD functions on an entity so as to not have to write generic code myself. That's what the scaffolder is for right? What am I missing here and am I confusing Razor with Blazor or what's going on?

Comment: @HenkHolterman There we go, that's what I needed to hear. So i'm trying to generate razor pages which are the .cshtml files while I was looking to generate components actually with the .razor extension but for that there is no code generation. Well that clears it up. Thx Henk.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So is there any way to generate a CRUD page based on an Entity in a Blazor application? Because it would actually be perfect for just this functionality and then add different things through my components that are already setup. 

I put everything in the same project and am now at a stage that I get this error: "Failed to compile the project in memory: Components namespace does not exists in..."

Comment: As far as I know, there is no officially supported scaffolding tool for creating CRUD pages/components based on an entity within a Blazor application. My advice is to avoid mixing Razor Pages and Blazor until you have a better understanding of one or the other framework. Sorry that my previous question didn't help you. I couldn't know how much you knew until you answered.

Comment: Additionally (realising I duplicated information from previous comments) if you really need scaffold support for generating CRUD pages, perhaps you should consider creating a Razor Pages application instead. The scaffolder is not without its faults (too many to detail here) but at least it provides a starting point.